# Showing "Program type already present: android.arch.core.BuildConfig " error when rebuilding app

Tags: android, android-studio

When I rebuilding my project..I'm getting the following error message. Any help wound be grateful to solve this.I also have implemented Room Persistence Library according to  this  [link](https://medium.com/@ajaysaini.official/building-database-with-room-persistence-library-ecf7d0b8f3e9)!

---**Build Window**---

```
Program type already present: android.arch.core.BuildConfig
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: 
android.arch.core.BuildConfig, sources=[Unknown source file], tool 
name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

---**Log**---

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
at ...
```

---**dependencies**---

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.9.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.1'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:' + rootProject.archRoomVersion
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:' + rootProject.archRoomVersion
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

--**Edit**--

I'm including the following code to point out the origin of error

--**Build:Gradle(Project)**--

```
ext {
buildToolsVersion = "25.0.2"
supportLibVersion = "25.3.1"
archRoomVersion = "1.0.0-alpha1"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be cleared by updating the following,

-- **Build:Gradle(Project)** --

```
ext {
buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
archRoomVersion = "1.1.1"
}
```

The problem lies with the tutorial provided which wasn't updated recently.